# System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException Se ha producido un error al obtener información del proveedor de la base de datos

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework, odp.net

Estoy realizando una aplicacion con `ODP.NET Oracle.ManagedDataAcces.EntitiFramework` esta es mi cadena de conexión:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));User Id=DB_DIGITAL_204;Password=123456;
```

Al realizar las consultas me funciona bien. Cuando cambio el host a una servidor no remoto (`HOST=30.3.3.204`) me sale la siguiente excepción:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException was unhandled  Message=An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.  
InnerException:
   Message=The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
   Source=EntityFramework       
   InnerException: 
        DataSource=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess            
        Message=Comunicación de Oracle: fallo al conectar al servidor o al analizar la cadena de conexión

        Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver
        InnerException:
             Message=Comunicación de Oracle: fallo al conectar al servidor o al analizar la cadena de conexión                 
             Source=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess                 
             InnerException: 
                  Message=No se pudo realizar una llamada a SSPI; consulte la excepción interna.                      
                  InnerException: 
                       Message=No hay credenciales disponibles en el paquete de seguridad
```

Probé conectarme al `Host` remoto con otro cliente (`SQL Dveloper`) y funciona correctamente. ¿Cúal es el problema? Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, la versión de Oracle instalada en el servidor no remoto es diferente a la que si lo es? Tal vez sea mas nueva y tu adaptador ODP.Net no se pueda usar con dicha versión.

Answer (score 0):

El nombre de la instancia, usuario/contraseña serán diferentes en el entorno remoto del local habitualmente.

Puedes utilizar la herramienta **`tnsping`** de `Oracle` con los `Local Naming Parameters`  (`tnsnames.ora`) para comprobar al conectividad con el `host` remoto

En lugar de utilizar `tnsnames.ora` utiliza una cadena de conexión del tipo:

```
Data Source=BaseDatosOrable;User Id=usuario;Password=claveAcceso;Integrated Security=no;
```